# how to get correct exit code via java code from an spark app in cluster mode in kubernetes

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm running a java spark app in cluster mode in kubernetes. At the moment I'm
using the SparkLauncher's java API to add a listener to get
notifications about the lifecycle from the running app. As far as I
understand the listener way is not fully implemented when running in
k8s. the code i'm using closes the spark context on the driver pod. this
results is state LOST in the java sparkapphandle.listener.

So my question is, which technically way should I use to get notified
about the state of the app I submitted. At the moment it is enough to
know the exit code of the app, not the progress or the state of every
executor.

I see the following tools

- history server
- rest api
- task metrics
- watcher api (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/WatchExample.java)

I mean I see logs which contains infos i'm interested in. I believe it
is the class LoggingPodStatusWatcher.scala which logs these infos.

So can someone help me to point me to the smartest way to gather the
exit code programmatically from the app I started

thx
marko

Answer (score 0):

My latest findings how to answer this questions, is to use the fabric8io library by using the wach api.

examples can be found here.
https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-tests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/mock/PodTest.java